# Using JQuery with a ASP.NET TextBox Controls to Switch Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, user-controls

I have coded a User Login screen in ASP.NET (VB). Following the username and password screen the user is required to enter two random digits of their PIN.

There are two ASP:TextBox controls on this form called PIN1TextBox and PIN2TextBox and both objects have a maximum length of 1.

I would like to know how to set the focus to PIN2TextBox automatically after a single character has been entered into PIN1TextBox e.g. it jumps focus.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PIN1TextBox" TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="1" runat="server" style="border-color:#A5A3A3;border-style:solid; border-width:1px; width:20px; text-align:center;"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="PIN2TextBox" TextMode="Password" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" MaxLength="1" runat="server" style="border-color:#A5A3A3;border-style:solid; border-width:1px; width:20px; text-align:center;"></asp:TextBox>
```

The website is cross browser enabled e.g. IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari so ideally the solution should work on all browsers. Not to worry if this part is over complicated though.

I hope you can help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
$("#<%= PIN1TextBox.ClientID %>").keyup(function () {
   if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
      $("#<%= PIN2TextBox.ClientID %>").focus();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Learner - I added this jQuery in my script tags at the top of my page but it didn't seem to work so I moved to the bottom and magic it works. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

I can cook up a jquery solution which is

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim()) {
        var $next = $(this).next('input');
        $next.focus();
    }
});
```

But you might wanna consider adding separate classes for this input and append it to the 'input' in the selectors